# pygame can't proceed successfully

Tags: python-2.7, pygame

```
import pygame
from sys import exit
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600,170),0,32) 
pygame.display.set_caption("Hello World!") //set caption
background = pygame.image.load('bg.jpeg').convert //load picture and convert it
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()
    screen.blit(background,(0,0))
    pygame.display.update() //refresh
```

The Error I get :

```
 File "/Users/huangweijun/PycharmProjects/untitled1/first.py", line 12, in<module>     

    screen.blit(background,(0,0))

    TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not builtin_function_or_method
```

i have download pygame

i don't know how to solve this issue.

Comment: can you try with  just `background = pygame.image.load("bg.jpeg")` instead of `background = pygame.image.load('bg.jpeg').convert`

Comment: thank you.the problem is solved

Comment: so this basically means you don't have to convert the image

Comment: @usb-pineapple Didn't you simply forget the parentheses after `convert`? `background = pygame.image.load('bg.jpeg').convert` --> `background = pygame.image.load('bg.jpeg').convert()`

Comment: jDo is right. You forgot the parentheses behind `convert`. All images should be converted for performance reasons, so don't just remove it as Nishant Singh suggests.

Answer (score 0):

The first argument of the function `screen.blit` is a pygame `Surface`. Think of this as a screen to draw to. You are specifying an object of the class `Image`. This will not work for you cannot draw to an image.

Replace `background` with `screen` and add `background` as an argument between `screen` and `(0,0)`. You code should now look like this:

```
import pygame
from sys import exit
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600,170),0,32) 
pygame.display.set_caption("Hello World!") //set caption
background = pygame.image.load('bg.jpeg').convert //load picture and convert it
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()
    screen.blit(screen,background,(0,0))
    pygame.display.update() //refresh
```

Answer (score 0):

pineapple, Looks like the issue here is in this line:

`background = pygame.image.load('bg.jpeg').convert`

I think what you wanted to use was: 
`background = pygame.image.load('bg.jpeg').convert_alpha()`

Hopefully that's what you were looking for!

EDIT: You could have also just added parentheses after the `convert()` Oops!
Try them both and see what happens!

-Travis